# How does Linux kernel handle the concurrent file lookup

Tags: concurrency, filesystems, linux-kernel

Assuming there are two processes [looking up](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/dcache.c#L1923) a file at the same time, and this file does not existed in the dcache yet. These two lookups will return NULL ([dentry](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/dcache.h#L103)) to the process.

My question is that how does Linux kernel ensure that after a failed dentry lookup, it only creates one dentry?

Answer (score 0):

```
1912 /**
1913  * d_lookup - search for a dentry
1914  * @parent: parent dentry
1915  * @name: qstr of name we wish to find
1916  * Returns: dentry, or NULL
1917  *
1918  * d_lookup searches the children of the parent dentry for the name in
1919  * question. If the dentry is found its reference count is incremented and the
1920  * dentry is returned. The caller must use dput to free the entry when it has
1921  * finished using it. %NULL is returned if the dentry does not exist.
1922  */
```

`d_lookup` does not create any `dentry` objects by yourself. Take a look at the `do_filp_open` logic and it shows how `dentries` are created.